# Entity Framework update table with rowguid

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am using MERGE REPLICATION on my server and now all tables have a `rowguid`, the last models generated before this change is working very good, but now the new table I imported (using database-first) get the `rowguid` and making impossible to update, I deleted this column in `Model.edmx` and I got this error.

> Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 551: Column Location.rowguid in table Location must be mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can backup your database then restore it on another computer without preserving replication settings which will remove all replication traces inclusing the added rowguid columns, then you can generate your entity from the restored database.

[image: Restore Database Replication Setting]