# How to handle rowguid for replication in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, replication

I'm having some trouble trying to [INSERT/UPDATE] records in our database since we have implemented a replication scenario. (SQL SERVER 2012)

When I try to save an entity I get these messages:

Updating columns with the rowguidcol property is not allowed.

The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Sometimes this one

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Job' with unique index 'MSmerge_index_1345596032'. The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).

I'm a bit lost as to how to generate the edmx model, without it having the rowguid being in the Entities.

The pattern I use to save

```
        var entry = db.Entry(job);

        entry.State = (job.JobId == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return entry.Entity.JobId;
```

How do I use Ef and replication without going crazy with the rowguid?

**UPDATE:**

I have set in the modal browser the rowguid property of StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity, it seems to working again, but I don't know the impact of doing it that way.

What is the best way to deal with Replication with EF??

Comment: You're talking about Merge Replication right?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Entity Framework but is there a way to exclude the rowguid column from the column lists?  Merge will handle the rowguid column for you.

Comment: @Brandon, Yes I think it is Merge @Brandon(bis)The replication was added after the dev process, I don't know what impact that has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your development database must not be configured for replication scenarios, you should be able to map your database without rowguid columns, ask for a database backup to the DBA and then restore it without preserve the replication settings. Check this link: [Entity Framework update table with rowguid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624012/entity-framework-update-table-with-rowguid)

Comment: I'll give you the answer, but yeah I found that I had to set the replication field  to GUID in the Database Mapper, this solved the issue ... completly forgot I asked this..

Answer (score 1):

try to change your model diagram (.edmx), where you have to change the StoreGeneratedPattern property from "None" to "Computed".

Comment: Nice. Note, you need to click on the `rowguid`. I have searched on the global Properties first.